# What is the Object given to Lock

Tags: c#, locking

I use `lock` to add items to `list` in parallel foreach as below.

```
        Parallel.ForEach(list, i =>
            {
                //...

                lock (LockThread)
                {
                    _asset.Add(...);
                }
            });
```

LockThread is a `static readonly object`.

What I understand was that `lock` makes block single threaded and will not allow multitasking there.

So why I should give it an object ? What does it do?

Why can't I just write

```
lock {...}
```

Comment: As a side note, you may want to rethink your `_asset` collection and `lock` and perhaps utilise `ConcurrentBag` in conjunction with `Parallel.ForEach()`.  `lock`ing something is somewhat of an expensive operation and limits scalability.  Check out .NET's _[Task Parallelism Library (TPL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given `object` the code in at most one `lock` statement that uses that object can execute at at time.

If you have

```
var obj1 = new object();
var obj2 = new object();
```

and then

```
lock (obj1) {
   // code block 1a
}

lock (obj1) {
   // code block 1b
}

lock (obj2) {
   // code block 2
}
```

then code block 1a and code block 2 can execute concurrently, as can code block 1b and 2. Code blocks 1a and 1b will not be able to execute at the same time. And, of course, only one thread at a time can execute code block 1a and likewise for the others.

Comment: so is that all ? i mean nothing else to use it for?. its important of course but i want to know

Comment: There are a lot of subtleties to explore about the right way to use `lock` but this is basically what the statement is for.

Answer (score 0):

It depend's on object that you want to share between different thread, if the object is [ThreadSafe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8544e2s.aspx) then you don't need put in lock but for non-threadsafe should make sure only one thread access the object at same time

For example you can find the difference between [Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx) and [ConcurrentCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you apply `lock` you basically say, "From now on only 1 can use this scope" the locking taken place on `block of memory` that is marked as `blocked` so we use the most basic form that hold memory that is the `object` class.

```
lock (refrenceMemoryObject) {
    // Scope
}
```

You can read more about lock [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)